# Symfony 6 - Connection refused for localhost

Tags: symfony, localhost

Im using docker (from symfony docs - https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker) and in symfony 6 i've reciceved:

```
Failed to connect to localhost port 443 after 0 ms: Connection refused for "https://localhost/products".
```

This addres in browser returns json with products.

This is controller:

```
  <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ApiController extends AbstractController
{   
    #[Route('/apire', name: 'api')]
    public function fetchGitHubInformation()
    {
        $client = HttpClient::create();
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://localhost/products');
        
        $content = $response->getContent();
        $content = $response->toArray();


        return new JsonResponse($content);
    }
}
```

and this is netstat from caddy docker container:

```
/srv/app # netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:45991        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2019          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/caddy
tcp        0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/caddy
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/caddy
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you load your site at `https://[::1]/products`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i can't - Couldn't connect to server for "https://[::1]/products".

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález can this be related to ssl? I have https crossed out

Comment: @pystopapo, have you created a self signed cert for your localhost? For testing it should work with *http (port 80)* instead of *https (port 443)*

Comment: @Bossman yes, i'd installed it by symfony server:ca:install, but it doesn't work properly on docker (crossed out https). However it doesn't matter that i used http or https localhost - it always returns Connection refused

Answer (score 2):

Solution comes from here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cDXJq_RyNc

When i change to http://caddy/products - everything works.

Comment: Please read "[Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)"

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the IP address from `localhost(:port)` to my windows IP address `192.168.x.x(:port)` and it worked!

If you have port, replace (:port) with your port. ex : http://192.168.x.x:8080

How to get your IP address ;

```
1 . Open cmd
2 . ipconfig
3 . Get the address from IPv4 Address.
```

Comment: Please note that's the IP address within your local network, not a private local address. Firewall aside, that normally implies that your web server is serving your development site to other computers. This may or may not be what you need or want.